HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden after entering ee.Authenticate() token code
This is my first time using geemap and ee libraries. I have followed every step and wrote the code below:
import geemap
import ee

ee.Authenticate()

After getting the token code from the pop-up window, When I enter the token code I recieve the following error:

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden


Do you have an Earth Engine account and project?  Have you gone through the authentication guide?  https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/auth#authentication_details
